# AngularJS 'filter' to intercept all state changes?

Tags: angularjs

How might I create the equivalent of a server-side filter in an Angular app when loading different controllers?

My objective is to allow deep linking into my app, but detect when a HTTP Basic Authorization token is not in memory for the Angular app and pull from local storage (if it exists).

I can do this with each controller but I'd like to handle it in one location that the controllers don't have to be aware of.

Comment: [Interceptors](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: @calebboyd I suppose I could solve this problem by intercepting each HTTP request before it's sent but I'm still interested in whether or not the filter concept can be implemented in Angular.

Comment: From your description: `'filter concept' == 'which intercepts http requests' == Interceptors`. Can you elaborate more on what server implementation uses that concept, and how you would like to use it on the client?

Comment: Let's say I want users to be able to book-mark any page in my app. This means that the entry point to my app could be any of my controllers. I would like a common location to detect that someone is coming to my app for the first time (or reloading) and take some action. Hope that helps... edited the question a bit to try to clear that up.

Comment: If you have initialization code it should go in `angular.module("myApp").config` or `angular.module("myApp").run` blocks

Comment: @calebboyd You've got it - looks like the run block is what I need. Make it an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you actually need to initialize application state before you move into the controllers, this can be done in either a

`angular.module('myApp').config` block

or an `angular.module('myApp').run` block